# How to preselect a <select> list item in using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, select

I have this markup and javascript. I cannot get the "T" option (for example) to preselect on page load. Is it possible?

```
    <select id="serviceType" name="serviceType" class="form-control">
      <option value="S">S</option>
      <option value="T">T</option>
      <option value="X">X</option>
    </select>
    <script>
        //document.getElementById("serviceType").selectedIndex = "T"; // did not work
      var e = document.getElementById("serviceType");
      e.options[e.selectedIndex].value = "T"; // does not work
    </script>
```

Note: "T" is dynamic at page build time in PHP from a DB call. So my script actually looks like this:
`= "<? echo $_POST['serviceType']; ?>"`

Comment: In your comment below, you state that the page is rendered through php, and that you know the value which should be preselected? So why then not have php apply the correct value/selected attributes directly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your commented out line did not work because the `selectedIndex` property of a select element expects an ordinal index of the element your wanted selected.

```js
document.getElementById("serviceType").selectedIndex = 1;
```

```html
<select id="serviceType" name="serviceType" class="form-control">
  <option value="S">S</option>
  <option value="T">T</option>
  <option value="X">X</option>
</select>
```

If you want to set by the *value* then you can also set the `value` property of the element

```js
document.getElementById("serviceType").value= "T";
```

```html
<select id="serviceType" name="serviceType" class="form-control">
  <option value="S">S</option>
  <option value="T">T</option>
  <option value="X">X</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, I know that @Jamiec -- but I am trying to set the option selection based on a string value and not a numeric index.

Comment: @H.Ferrence ah I see, I ve updated then (Original answer was based on your commented out line)

Comment: perfect @Jamiec -- that the cleanest and most condensed answer of the pack. Thanks for helping!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Just do it like this:

```
var e = document.getElementById("serviceType");
e.value="T";
```

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/7u8p2bg5/).

Comment: You most welcome! Good to know that you got your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `value` of the `select` tag not the `option`:

```
var e = document.getElementById("serviceType");
e.value = "T";
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is using selected in html5

```
<select id="serviceType" name="serviceType" class="form-control">
  <option value="S">S</option>
  <option value="T" selected>T</option>
  <option value="X">X</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Understood. The value of "T" actually comes from page render in PHP from a db call so "T" is not static every time.

Comment: in html5, that would jsust be `selected` - in (X)HTML it would have been `selected="selected"`

Comment: @Jamiec everything I learnt is from uni so my teacher forces us to follow xml also :D

Comment: Your lecturer needs a new book.